# Cannot connect to the aurora postgres database through RDS proxy

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, amazon-rds-proxy

I am setting up a aurora postgres database and a rds proxy associated to the db, but I cannot connect to that db through the proxy.

So I was checking some basic configurations. Such as subnet routes table, security group inbound and outbound rules and Network ACLs, everything seems good, like shown in the screen shots below.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
When I was trying to test the proxy endpoint with this:

```
nc -vz proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com 5432
```

I got this error:
nc: connectx to proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port 5432 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out

I also checked the local firewall, and it is off. The status of proxy and db are available. so I am really confused about this.

Btw, at first I was trying to connect to db using these two commands but got same time out error.

```
psql -h proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com -p 5432 -d postgres -U aurora-postgresql-sm
```

```
psql "host=proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com port=5432 dbname=postgres user=aurora-postgresql-sm sslmode=require"
```

psql: error: connection to server at "proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.24.200), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
connection to server at "proxy-test-de.proxy-cu4jou8grpwg.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.13.52), port 5432 failed: Operation timed out
Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

What should I do now?

Thanks so much for your help.